# Properties of Discrete Time Continuous State Markov Process

Tags: functional-analysis, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a problem setup that reduces to finding the stationary state of a discrete time continuous state stationary Markov process. Is that state unique, as it is in the discrete state case?

Specifically, given the stationary Markov process:
$$f_{i+1}(x) = \int \mathcal{L}(x|y) f_i(y) \operatorname{d}y,$$ where $\mathcal{L}(x|y)$ is positive semi-definite and satisfies $\int \mathcal{L}(x|y) \operatorname{d} x = 1\ \forall y$, does the stationary state:
$$f(x) = \int \mathcal{L}(x|y) f(y) \operatorname{d}y$$ have all of these properties:

1. exists,
2. unique,
3. positive semi-definite, and
4. the eigenfunction that has the largest eigenvalue?

The last two are satisfied if a continuous version of the [Perron–Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) can be shown.

Is it enough to say that the process can be approximated arbitrarily well by a sequence of discrete time discrete state processes defined by a sequence of partitions of $x$ with norm $\rightarrow 0$?

Add: does this qualify as a [Harris chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harris_chain) (I'm having trouble understanding the notation in the Wikipedia article)? Both the Wikipedia article and [this Quora question](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-Harris-chain) reference section 6.8 of ["Probability" by Durrett](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521765390), but I have no way of accessing that work right now.

Conjecture: uniqueness requires [irriducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducibility_(mathematics)) of $\mathcal{L}(x|y)$, and convergence requires either: the set which defines the domain of $f_i$ is closed, or at least one measure of central tendency for each dimension must converge to somewhere within the domain. These are separable requirements (e.g. $\mathcal{L}(x|y)=\delta(x-y)$ holds all distributions stationary [maximal non-uniqueness], $\mathcal{L}(x|y)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\left(-\frac{[x-my-\mu]^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$ for $x,y\in(-\infty,\infty)$ converges iff $|m| < 1$ [reparameterizing to $x'\in (0,1)$ shows that it converges to a delta function on the boundary]).

Comment: The basic issue here that is not present with a finite state space is tightness, i.e. proving that the process spends "most" of its time in a compact set (where the compact you choose depends on what you mean by "most"). For example, discrete Brownian motion is not tight and has no stationary distribution. Once you have tightness the situation is not so different from the discrete space case.

Comment: By the way, your process is time-homogeneous, but typically not stationary.

Comment: @Ian What are the additional constraints that have to be satisfied to ensure the four desired properties?

Comment: I don't know about necessary and sufficient conditions, just sufficient conditions. These basically boil down to checking recurrence.

Comment: Is Riemann integrability of $\mathcal{L}(x|y)$ sufficient?

Comment: No. For instance it could be that L (x|y) is supported entirely in, say, $[y+1,y+2] $, in which case the process just marches off to $+\infty $. This is a bit like the "random" walk that always goes one step to the right.

Comment: Would you say that $\mathcal{L}(x|y) \propto \exp\left(-\frac{(4x - y-12)^2}{30}\right)$ approximates that description well? Because this one holds $f(x) = \exp\left(-\frac{(x-4)^2}{2}\right)$ stationary. The natural function held stationary by a uniform distribution between $[y+1,y+2]$, for example, is any constant function, though that means it cannot be normalized. The fact that in the Gaussian example I gave $x$ and $y$ not having the same scale seems significant.

Comment: The tightness issue no longer matters if you only want a stationary measure instead of a stationary distribution. Indeed if you move a $U (1,2) $ distance to the right at each step then the Lebesgue measure is stationary.

Comment: In your Gaussian example the point is that $x $ is centered around $(y+12)/4$ which is considerably closer to 0 than $y $ if $y$ is large. Thus "soon enough" you move back in toward zero which is precisely the recurrence that I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Could you recommend a reference, @Ian, that goes describes these properties, preferably with examples and problems to work out?

Comment: Unfortunately I learned this on a very ad hoc basis, so I can't really help you there.